# White rectangular space in chat view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have simple chat app, and when I run my project there is white rectangular like image. I check may times my code, I did not detect any error. when I add toolbar, this rectangular padding bottom, any idea?

**Screenshot:**
[image]

**ChatView:**

```
   struct chatList : View {

   var body : some View{
    
    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
        
        VStack{
            
            ForEach(Eachmsg){i in
                
                chatCell(data: i)
            }
        }
        
    }.padding(.horizontal, 15)
    .background(Color.white)
    
  }}

struct chatCell : View {

var data : msgdataType

var body : some View{
    
    HStack{
        
        if data.myMsg{
            
            Spacer()
            
            Text(data.msg)
                .padding()
                .background(Color("color"))
                .clipShape(msgTail(mymsg: data.myMsg))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        else{
            
            Text(data.msg)
                .padding()
                .background(Color("gray"))
                .clipShape(msgTail(mymsg: data.myMsg))
            
            Spacer()
        }
        
    }.padding(data.myMsg ? .leading : .trailing, 55)
    .padding(.vertical,10)
    }
    }
```

**msgdataType:**

```
struct msgdataType : Identifiable {
var id : Int
var msg : String
var myMsg : Bool
}
```

**Eachmsg:**

```
 var Eachmsg = [

msgdataType(id: 0, msg: "New Album Is Going To Be Released!!!!", 
myMsg: false),.....
```

Comment: It's not any custom view, just a space. Try removing Spacer and it will work fine

Comment: @udbhateja Spacer() to where?

Comment: In ChatCell, HStack you have added 2 Spacer, one if if condition and other in else condition

Comment: I do but, not removed

Comment: Please post code for Eachmsg and msgDataType

Comment: Edit you question and post it there so that others can also help

Comment: @udbhateja tnx so much , but it is still same for me

Answer (score 1):

In your chatCell, the blank space showing is for message with `myMsg=true`

```
if data.myMsg {
        Spacer()
        Text(data.msg)
            .padding()
            .background(Color("color"))
            .clipShape(msgTail(mymsg: data.myMsg))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
```

Try changing `foregroundColor` to `.red` or .`blue` or change `background` to valid value and you will see the message.